# I can't 'flag' 'not constructive' when a question has a bounty

Tags: support, bounties, flags

A long-term bugbear of mine is the protection that a bounty affords from closing. Every so often, I find that someone's gone and posted a bounty on a question that deserves to be migrated or just terminated, but I can't vote.

When I learned about the new feature of *flags* for the close reasons, I thought that my prayers were answered here. I could flag as non-constructive and leave it to a mod to decide.

Sadly, the flag system seems to notice that I have rep enough to vote to close, and then rejects the vote due to the bounty. If it's going to work this way, I wish that the 'does not belong here' option were disabled for bountied questions altogether.

Of course, what I really wish was for the protective field to be eliminated, and for questions with bounties to be closable, with the bounty refunded.

Comment: Moderators can refund a bounty, so flagging using the "other" field should work if you can convince a moderator that the question should be closed.

Answer (score 11):

To get around the protective field, flag the question with "other," and explain why the question deserves to be closed.  The moderator can refund the bounty and close the question, if he agrees.

There are two ways to build a UI with interlocking elements.  The first way is to disable the elements that do not apply (in this case, the vote to close on a question with a bounty).  The second way is to allow the user to use the UI element, perform a check for validity, and then notify the user if the action is invalid.  The latter approach has the advantage of teaching people how the system works.