# Please stop bounties from turning off community moderation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, vote-to-close, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't we close questions with bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties)
>   [Allow users to vote to close bountied questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions)
>   [How to prevent your question being closed? Just post a bounty on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140206/how-to-prevent-your-question-being-closed-just-post-a-bounty-on-it)

**tl;dr: Please get rid of "This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed"**

Questions with bounties on them can't be closed:

[image: Can't be closed message]

This is by design, and the recommended course of action is to flag for moderator attention, at which point they'll decide whether to refund the bounty and close the question or not.<sup>[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties) [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97345/i-cant-flag-not-constructive-when-a-question-has-a-bounty)</sup>

**But why should a bounty disable regular community moderation?**

We should be able to cast close votes on bountied questions as usual, and if a question gets enough, the bounty's refunded and the question closed.

An obvious benefit would be reduced burden on moderators, but I doubt that this is really a significant part of their workload.  More important is allowing the entire community's wisdom to be brought to bear.

Consider this question: [Some bottleneck OS resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594640/some-bottleneck-os-resource)

> Having a simple MFC application with web browser controller that navigates to some site and then to another one on and on.
>
> Using a powerfull machine (16 cores and lots of memory) OS is Server 2008 R2. I can see when launching my app over 30 instances I'm getting the OS UI (each window including my app, mspaint, taskmgr etc..) become very sluggish and slow.
>
> I have monitored the machine resources (CPU, memory and GDI objects) but it seems that all of them are not even close to be in some level of stress.
>
> What is the problematic resource that influence the machine in such way?
>
> 10x, Guy

It doesn't look like a good question: somewhat poorly written, vague, not a ton of information, etc.  **I would vote to close this question.**  However, I don't do much work with MFC and maybe there's something I'm missing.  (I can readily imagine a similarly bad looking question with the extremely concrete answer: [CPython's Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).)

I'm comfortable casting a vote to close, not closing unilaterally.  Flagging for a moderator just passes the buck to them, when the correct action is letting the community weigh in.

Comment: Hm, you need to wait for a couple of days before setting a bounty, and if the question survived that long...

Comment: It could just be unnoticed for that long.

Comment: I see this often enough happening in "niche" tags. I usually flag for moderator attention which works just fine. Although I don't think that this puts a huge workload on them, +1 for getting world's attention on this.

Comment: @Jake223 Yes, obviously. Let's solve _that_ problem instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent your question being closed? Just post a bounty on it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140206/how-to-prevent-your-question-being-closed-just-post-a-bounty-on-it); also: [Why can't we close questions with bounties?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/why-cant-we-close-questions-with-bounties)

Answer (score 1):

Post closed. Bounty Removed. Thanks for letting us know about it.